# VSTest Task running v1 when v2 expected, vstestLocation ignored

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to use Azure Pipelines to build a class library.  My `azure-pipelines.yml` looks like this:

```
variables:
  solution: 'MySolution.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'
steps: 
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
      otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:FrameworkCore10'
```

However, the task runs from a different location, and judging by that it seems to be Test Platform v1 (TP v1): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`.  Judging from the Github issues for [azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20label%3A%22Area%3A%20Test%22%20v2%20is%3Aopen), it seems that they shipped TP v2 sometime earlier this year (2018).

How can I make sure I'm actually using TP v2?

Update: I've now opened an issue on the pipelines github repo: [Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks#8911](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8911)

Comment: Did you try using the VSTest platform installer? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=vsts

Comment: @DanielMann I had not tried that; I assumed TP v2 would be packaged with the hosted VS2017 build agent.  However, I did try just now and I don't notice any difference in behavior, including when I remove the `vstestLocation` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the Location doesn't use the correct location is because `vstestLocation` needs the `vstestLocationMethod=location` argument as well. Otherwise the default value `version` [is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops).

However, when those arguments are specified, instead of packaging the list of tested binaries, it seems to expand them into the command line, which might cause a `##[error]Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG` if the binaries' names form a string that is too long.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because  at least you provided an answer!  FWIW, I don't know if this would solve the issue because I've long since moved on an am no longer trying to repro this.